# Asynchronously running a ruby script from ruby

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, sinatra, watir-webdriver, child-process

Based on an external redis queue, I want a Sinatra application to run a script like this:

`ruby fetch_vin.rb vin_number_123`

This will fire up `watir-webdriver` and report to the queue appropriately. When the script is finished, everything but the Sinatra app should close.

It seems however that `Thread`, as well as `exec` and `spawn` are all blocking when ran from inside ruby.

How do I fire & forget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Process#spawn`:

```
pid = Process.spawn("ruby fetch_vin.rb vin_number_123")
Process.detach(pid)
```

I think the bit you were missing was calling `detach` after the process was spawned. This will detach and let both processes continue to run. Will work for any command, not just a ruby script.

See [`Process` Ruby Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Process.html#M002230) for more details.